# Add a custom script on "place order" button on woocommerce checkout page

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, checkout

I'm trying to add this script on "place order" button of woocommerce checkout page:

```
$('#place_order').addClass('disabled');
```

but If I put it inside the footer.php file it doesn't work.

I've find a resource that suggests to me to override the woocommerce `checkout.js` file make a clone inside `/my-theme/woocommerce` folder but now I don't understand where to put my custom script in order to make it works.

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Your script has to be put inside the `ready` handler, but still you have one problem, on each ready event ( whenever DOM is fully loaded ) woocommerce update the Order Review section through Ajax, so this action will remove your `disabled` class from the `Place Order` button.

You can use the custom event `updated_checkout` which will be triggered at the end of each `Update Order Review` ajax action.

Do some thing like this.

```
function add_checkout_script() { ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).on( "updated_checkout", function(){
                $('#place_order').addClass('disabled');
            });         

    </script>

<?php       
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'add_checkout_script' );
```